# Exception picking a image from gallery (SD Card) for use on my app... java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, android-gallery

i am picking images on my app with android, and i dont know why, sometimes i got an exception, i think it's allways i select a image with more than 400 or 500 kb's but i am not sure. Why? because when i select small images of 100 kb i dont get the exception, and when i get images with high KB or MB, it crash WITH `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`.  **BUT VERY IMPORTANT: it crashes on the emulator but ALSO CRASH ON MY PHONE, is not a failure of the emulator.**

this is my code:

```
changeImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
            }
        }); 



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

        switch(requestCode) {
        case 1:
        {
            setResult(1);
            finish();    
        }
        case ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                selectedPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                //profileImage.setImageBitmap(selectedPhoto);
                profileImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedPhoto, 80, 80, false));
            }
        }
    }
```

profileImage is a ImageView of my layout. and i use scaled butmap to resice the image to 80x80

please give me some help with this exception, i need to solve it

this is the exception:

```
 01-31 12:38:37.531: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:375)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:171)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:196)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.GPSLoc.Configuration.onActivityResult(Configuration.java:253)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3595)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3001)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3047)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:112)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1721)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
    01-31 12:38:37.552: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I am facing same problem, What is the solution for this @AndroidUser99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmap.createScaledBitmap method as long as I have researched has a highpoint of memory consumption and produces that error, but, I'm not totally sure about it. Anyway it is JAVA API and you cannot go deeper.

You can do the next:

```
//create a Drawable with your image as parameter
BitmapDrawable d= new BitmapDrawable(youBitmap);
//define bounds for your drawable       
int left =0;
int top = 0;
int right=80;
int bottom=80;

Rect r = new Rect(left,top,right,bottom);
//set the new bounds to your drawable       
d.setBounds(r);
//set the drawable as view of your image view
profileImage.setImageDrawable(d);
```

I have not tested this code, but it should work.

Comment: in which line does it crashes?